# How to end the LOAD DATA INFILE upon encountering a certain field

Tags: mysql, csv

Here is the SQL query I have so far:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'filename.csv'
INTO TABLE zt_accubid
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 4 LINES
```

I need to be able to end the process once a field with `value="xyz"` is encountered.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LOAD DATA INFILE` has no such option. There are a couple of workaraounds, though

- You could solve the problem outside MySQL by manipulating the file first
- As Alain Collins mentioned, if the column containing you marker has only unique values, and you don't have the `LOAD DATA` inside a transcation, you can use a unique key as a stopper.
- You can use a trigger on the table as a stopper
- If the marker is near the end of the table or the overhead is not important to you, you can do a full `LOAD DATA` into an interims table, then use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` to move only the relevant data into your final table
- Similarily you can load all data, then delete the irellevant part

Comment: Thanks. I went with loading all of the data then deleting the unneeded stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Sure - put a row in the database before the load, and put a unique key on it.  The LOAD should fail when it hits the duplicate.

Comment: This will only work, if all other values in this column are unique!